# A managed resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw" has not been declared in module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying create public route table using terraform but i'm facing following error.

> Error: Reference to undeclared resource
> │
> │   on ..\modules\rt\ressources.tf line 6, in resource "aws_route_table" "public":
> │    6:     gateway_id      = aws_internet_gateway.igw.id # routing with IGW
> │
> │ A managed resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw" has not been declared in module.public-rt.

Here is my **main.tf**

```
# Create VPC
module "vpc" {
  source            = "../modules/vpc"
  vpc_cidr_block    = "************"        
  vpc_tags          = { Name = "prod-vpc" }
  vpc_id            = module.vpc.vpcId       # get vpc id
}

# Create IGW
module "igw" {
  source            = "../modules/igw"
  igw_tags          = { Name = "prod-igw" }
  vpc_id            = module.vpc.vpcId       # attach vpc id to igw
  igw_id            = module.igw.igwId       # get igw id
}

# Create Public Subnet
module "public-sn" {
  source            = "../modules/sn"
  vpc_id            = module.vpc.vpcId 
  sn_az             = [ "************" ]
  sn_cidr           = [ "************" ]
  sn_tags           = [ "************" ] 
}

# Create Private Subnets
module "private-sn" {
  source            = "../modules/sn"
  vpc_id            = module.vpc.vpcId 
  sn_az             = [ "************", "************" ]
  sn_cidr           = [ "************", "************" ]
  sn_tags           = [ "************", "************" ] 
}

# Create Public Route Table
module "public-rt" {
  source            = "../modules/rt"
  vpc_id            = module.vpc.vpcId 
  vpc_cidr_block    = "************"  
  gateway_id        = module.igw.igwId
}
```

Here is my **ressources.tf**

```
# Routing table for public subnet
resource "aws_route_table" "public" {
  vpc_id            = var.vpc_id
 
  route {
    cidr_block      = var.vpc_cidr_block          # routing in the VPC
    gateway_id      = aws_internet_gateway.igw.id # routing with IGW
}
  tags              = var.public_rt_tags
}
```

Here is my **output.tf** in ../igw

```
# Declare output variables for igw id
output "igwId" {
    description = "IDs of the igw"
    value = aws_internet_gateway.igw.id
}
```

Many thanks in advance for your helping.

Comment: Have you actually tried setting the variable for the IGW in the route table specification, i.e., something like `gateway_id = var.internet_gateway_id`? Note that you would also have to add the variable to the `variables.tf` or whichever file you are using to define the variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marko. Resolved after adding the entry into vars.tf.

Answer (score 0):

Marko E. thanks for answering. I have updated my POST ressources.tf. Any other idea to help here ?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't see that you are already using the module output in the `main.tf`. You can disregard my answer.